# rust use filter with scan

Tags: rust, filter, iterator

I'm trying to remove some external mutable state from an iterator

```
fn main() {
    let non_increasing: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 0, 2, 6, 3, 9];
    let mut max_so_far = 0;
    for val in non_increasing
        .iter()
        .filter(|&&height| if height > max_so_far {max_so_far = height; true} else {false})
        {
            println!("{val}")
        }
}

# output
# 1
# 2
# 6
# 9
```

I have found I can do this using `scan` but this then makes applying the `filter` very difficult. In this case I'm only interested in positive numbers so there is a hack to get around it (though this hack works as long as you can be sure any given hard-coded value e.g. `i32::MIN` won't show up).

```
fn main() {
    let non_increasing: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 0, 2, 6, 3, 9];
    for val in non_increasing
        .iter()
        .scan(0, |max_so_far, &x|{
            if x > *max_so_far {
                *max_so_far = x;
                Some(x)
            } else {
                Some(i32::MIN)
            }
        })
        .filter(|&x| x != i32::MIN) 
        {
            println!("{val}")
        }
}

# output
# 1
# 2
# 6
# 9
```

However, I'd like a way to do this in a way which isn't just a hack, along the lines of

```rust
fn main() {
    let non_increasing: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 0, 2, 6, 3, 9];
    for val in non_increasing
        .iter()
        .scan_filter(0, |max_so_far, &x|{
            if x > *max_so_far {
                *max_so_far = x;
                (true, Some(x))
            } else {
                (false, Some(x))
            }
        })
        {
            println!("{val}")
        }
}

# output
# 1
# 2
# 6
# 9
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If I did this, I'd do the first one but add `move` to the closure so the mutable state is no longer external. Not sure if this is what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `Option<T>` is `IntoIterator`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let non_increasing: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 0, 2, 6, 3, 9];
    for val in non_increasing
        .iter()
        .scan(0, |max_so_far, &x| {
            if x > *max_so_far {
                *max_so_far = x;
                Some(Some(x))
            } else {
                Some(None)
            }
        })
        .flatten()
    {
        println!("{val}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, that's really slick, thanks.